# Unknown delay in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

There are 5000 milliseconds in 5 seconds. So if I run this code in Netlogo during that time:

```
every 0.001 [
  some-calls-in-the-middle
  tick
]
```

I expect to get 5000 ticks, but I'm getting no more than 150. Is there any way to map ticks to seconds more efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably whatever computation you're doing in `some-calls-in-the-middle` is taking approximately 1/150 second for NetLogo to perform.

`every` is only useful for making a snippet of code run less often — never for making it run more often. (It might help to give the [dictionary entry for `every`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#every) a careful read.)

Comment: Surely it is, I'm doing some intensive computations inside. Thanks